# Tutorial virus for apprenticeship

Tags: windows, gratis, antivirus

There's an excellent answer on SuperUser on [how to remove a virus](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit). I now want my trainees to not only understand that theoretically but turn it into practice.

Therefore I'm looking for a quite harmless virus, which is a bit difficult to get rid of, so at least some of the described steps need to be followed. So the EICAR Testvirus is not suitable, because it's too harmless.

Of course I will take some precautions, like using a PC that it not connected to the network *and* use a VM on that PC. However, if, in the remaining 0.1% of risk, one of the trainees manages to transfer the virus to another PC, I want to make sure that it cannot cause data loss etc.

Is there such a "demo virus" or "practice virus" available?

Requirements:

- the virus is able to infect Windows 10
- the virus does not spread itself across the network
- does not delete or encrypt files
- it may use CPU time
- it's free :-)